# Is there a way to statically send a notification from one AVD to another AVD on a button click?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a button on an activity and after clicking it an alert dialog comes up asking if you want to issue an appointment. When you click on yes, it loads the following activity,

AppointmentStatus.java

```
package com.roadraz.vcademy1;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class AppointmentStatus extends AppCompatActivity {

    LocalDatabase ld;
    NotificationManager notifyManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_appointment_status);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(AppointmentStatus.this);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Appointment request");
        mBuilder.setContentText("You have received an appointment request from a student!");
        mBuilder.setTicker("V-Cademy");

        Intent intentConfirm=new Intent(AppointmentStatus.this,ConfirmAppointment.class);
        TaskStackBuilder tStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        tStackBuilder.addParentStack(ConfirmAppointment.class);
        tStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intentConfirm);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=tStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notifyManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifyManager.notify(32,mBuilder.build());

    }

    // FOR OPTIONS MENU//
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu1; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.logout_home_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        ld = new LocalDatabase(AppointmentStatus.this);

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.logout_action) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(AppointmentStatus.this);
            alert.setTitle("Logout");
            alert.setMessage("Do you want to logout?");
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.logout);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ld.clearData();
                    Intent i = new Intent(AppointmentStatus.this, LoginPage.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }
        if(id == R.id.home_action){
            Intent intent=new Intent(AppointmentStatus.this,menu1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    //OPTIONS MENU END
}
```

appointment_status.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_appointment_status"
    tools:context="com.roadraz.vcademy1.AppointmentStatus">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The appointment request has been sent to the respective faculty"
        android:id="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#2a397c" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Please wait for the confirmation from the faculty......"
        android:id="@+id/textView27"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#2a397c"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/dv"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Status : "
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Pending..."
        android:id="@+id/textView182"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView28"
        android:textColor="#8f8f8f"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

On loading this activity I have set it to push a notification (but the notification comes up on the same device). So instead I want it to just statically send the notification to another AVD.

Comment: You'd need to do network communications between the two.  If they're not on the same wifi network, you'd need to have a web service intermediary.  And of course you'd need to have an app on both devices.  And the answer to that is way too broad for this site.

Comment: isn't there an option of using the emulator number on the top left corner for the communications between the two?

Comment: No.  They're separate devices.  Its like they were separate phones.  You need to communicate between the two like they were separate phones.